# I want to create a view above the soft keyboard

Tags: android, soft-keyboard

I am developing a Android Soft Keyboard. I want to create a layout above the Soft Keyboard. Whenever keyboard show on the screen the layout must visible.

You can easily understand my idea by seeing this image.

[image]

Comment: You can do that by using constraint layout and setting the view left , right and bottom constraint with parents.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Jawad Ahmend in the comments, it's possible to  attach the layout to the top of the keyboard by attaching it to the parent bottom using `ConstraintLayout`. You'd essentially need to do the following steps:

1. Set the `windowSoftInputMode` as `adjustResize` for your activity in the manifest.

   ```
   <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
   ```
2. Set your layout `visibility` to gone and add a layout constraint attaching it's bottom to the bottom of the parent.

   ```
   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout_B"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:visibility="gone">
   ```
3. Next, you need to monitor the soft keyboard state. To keep this short, let's just use the `KeyboardVisibilityEvent` [library](https://github.com/yshrsmz/KeyboardVisibilityEvent). Add the following line to your app's build.gradle and sync it.

   ```
   implementation 'net.yslibrary.keyboardvisibilityevent:keyboardvisibilityevent:2.3.0'
   ```
4. Add a keyboard listener in your activity to set your layout_B to become visible when the keyboard opens and you're done.

   ```
   KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(this) { keyboardIsOpen ->
       layout_B.visibility = if (keyboardIsOpen) {
           View.VISIBLE
       } else {
           View.GONE
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing the keyboard, its easy.  Just override onCreateInputView to return the view you want.  This can easily be a linear layout with your extra views and the keyboard itself in it.

The bigger problem I see is you have an EditText in there.  That's not going to work.  Tapping on the EditText is going to break the InputConnection to the actual app and cause...  unknown weird behavior.  I'm not even sure if the behavior will be defined across different OS versions.  It may cause the keyboard to immediately hide.  It may cause the keyboard to just stop working at all.  The OS isn't meant for that.